# C# Json => mysql. Need advice on how to handle it

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I'll give you a basic overview, summize it then ask the question so you all are informed as you can be. If you need more information please don't hesertate to ask.

Basic setup:

- Client is constantly in communication with a server providing json data to be serialized and processed.
- Client also needs to use this data and catalog it into a mysql server (main issue lay here)
- Client also, to a lesser extent, needs to store some of the data provided by the server into a local database specific to that client.

So as stated above I have a client that communicates with a server that outputs json to be processed. Now the question isn't about the json data or the communication with the server. More so to do with the remote and local databases and what approach I should take in the, I guess, dto.

Now - originally I was going to process it through a loop inserting individual segments of data into the database one after each other until it reaches the end of the paginated data. This almost immediately showed itself to be troublesome as deadlocks become a thing very, very quickly. So quickly in fact that after about 1682 inputs deadlocks went from 1 in 500 to 9 of 10 until the rollback function threw again to stop execution.

Here is really my question.

What suggestions would you have to handle a large amount (> 500k) of data initially, then after time as the database is populated, segmented sections (~1k).

I've looked into csv's, bulkinput and query building with stringbuilder. Operationally the string builder option executes the fastest, but I'm not sure on how it will scale once the data is constantly running through it and not just test files.

Any general advice or suggestions. How you think it would be best. Stuff like that. Anything would help. Just looking for real-world scearios from people that have handled a situation like this and can just guide me in the right direction.

As for being told what to do - I will research the option given should you want to be more vague. That's fine :)

Thanks again

Edit: Also - Do you think using Tasks or coding my own threads is a better option for such a situation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would choose Bulk Copy. It's easy to implement and the fastest way to store thousands of records in the database.

Useful article to read: http://ignoringthevoices.blogspot.si/2014/09/working-with-entity-framework-code.html

Comment: Thanks I'll have a read over it - I'll mark as answer if it works out for me. Going to try it now. Will update soon.

Comment: Worked out perfectly - Thank you. Not 100% sure if this is the approach I will have to take long term, depends on the client - at this point however that will do fine.